# string data can't be updated without changing the image in vue js

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I have a problem with updating data using vue js as the frontend and django as the backend
when updating the data with the data image is changed successfully. but when updating data without an image with an error.
i've fire test using postman and managed to update data without changing image. please find a solution

this is the method for updating the data

```
  ubah() {
  let datapengajarstaf = new FormData();
  datapengajarstaf.append("nama", this.datapengajarstaf.nama);
  datapengajarstaf.append("nip", this.datapengajarstaf.nip);
  datapengajarstaf.append("jobs", this.datapengajarstaf.jobs);
  datapengajarstaf.append("picture", this.gambar);
  _.each(this.datapengajarstaf, (value, key) => {
  datapengajarstaf.append(key, value);
        });
  axios
    .put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Detailpengajarstaff/"+this.id, datapengajarstaf,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
      }
    }
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.$router.push("/indexpengajarstaff");
      this.$q.notify({
        type: "positive",
        message: `Data berhasil ditambah.`
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.response.status === 422) {
        this.errors = [];
        _.each(err.response.data.errors, error => {
          _.each(error, e => {
            this.errors.push(e);
          });
        });
      }
    });
}
```

[this is for form-data when the data is updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AClwv.png)